# Magento - Fetch current domain and not base domain

Tags: php, magento

We are running one Magento install over multiple domains and are using a script to fetch information from the database to help users filter the products.

In our coding we have the `$_SERVER` function calling the store which seems to be store 1 (which is on domain 1), I was wondering what I would need to change to fetch the information from store 2 (which is on domain 2).

Comment: Are you talking about the getting store base url?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use the domain to determine what store you are going to access?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
echo Mage::getBaseUrl ();
```

will return the Store url only i.e. abc.com/store1.

In order to get the Main store URL (domain name), use the following code

```
echo Mage::getBaseUrl (Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
```

OR

you can get the current domain by the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is not available on Magento scheduler (cron) tasks (unless you put some effort on it) - just realised that today

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $_SERVER is not a function, but a predefined variable (associative array). Once u access the site from domain 2, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] will give u the right thing. It all depends on which domain you access the server from. I currently use this for a reseller website i have that has a lot of parked domains.

Hope that helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple domains then presumably you have multiple stores. Rather than reading the domain to determine which store you can just read the store directly:

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore()
```

`$store` then has all the information you need. For example, to retrieve the 'store code' that you set in the admin use,

```
$store->getCode()
```

As well as being object-orientated and hence easier to write, you benefit from the domains being completely configurable from admin, there will be no need to rewrite your code every time there is a change.